# How to resolve typescript errors for createContext in custom react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm following Advanced React Component Patterns on egghead and

I'm having a lot of problems

typing the function inside ToggleContext.Consumer :

```
interface IContextProps {
  on: boolean;
  toggle?: (flag: boolean) => void;
}
const ToggleContext = React.createContext<IContextProps | undefined>(undefined)

class Toggle extends React.Component {
  static On = ({children}:{children:React.ReactNode}) => (
    <ToggleContext.Consumer>
      {({on}) => (on ? children : null)}
    </ToggleContext.Consumer>
  )
  state = {on: false}
  toggle = () =>
    this.setState(
      ({on}) => ({on: !on}),
      () => this.props.onToggle(this.state.on),
    )
  render() {
    return (
      <ToggleContext.Provider
        value={{on: this.state.on, toggle: this.toggle}}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ToggleContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

How is the way please?

### UPDATE

I'd like to know how to type the function
inside ToggleContext.Consumer

```
<ToggleContext.Consumer>
      {({on}) => (on ? children : null)}
</ToggleContext.Consumer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear on which part you are facing the typing problem from your question, but here is an example that probably will help with typing for your class component.

```
import React from 'react'

interface IContextProps {
  on: boolean
  toggle?: (flag: boolean) => void
}

interface ToggleProps {
  onToggle: (on: boolean) => void
}

const ToggleContext = React.createContext<IContextProps | undefined>(undefined)

class Toggle extends React.Component<ToggleProps> {
  static On = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
    <ToggleContext.Consumer>{(ctx) => (ctx?.on ? children : null)}</ToggleContext.Consumer>
  )
  state = { on: false }
  toggle = () => {
    const { on } = this.state
    this.setState({ on: !on })
    this.props.onToggle(on)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ToggleContext.Provider value={{ on: this.state.on, toggle: this.toggle }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ToggleContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply  I've updated the post I'd like to type the function inside ToggleContext.Consumer  {({on}) => (on ? children : null)}

Comment: cool, so you cant use `{on}` as your context value since there is possibility it is undefined as been specified here (< IContextProps | undefined>). Therefore, you should have something like this. `{(ctx) => (ctx?.on ? children : null)}`